# ¿Cómo hacer una función javascript perpetua y adaptativa?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Intento hacer una animación distinta para cada uno de los círculos de color pese a que trabajan con tamaños parecidos:

- Color Rojo: [Frame2-Pos2-Size0b] El círculo aumenta hasta 300px y vuelve hasta 100px.
- Color Azul: [Frame-Pos-Size0a] El círculo aumenta hasta 300px y vuelve hasta 200px.
- Color Verde: [Frame3-Pos3-Size0c] El círculo disminuye hasta 300px y vuelve hasta 100px en el doble de tiempo que los otros disminuyen y aumentan 100px.

Todo esto adaptativo como aparece en el estilo css. Además, también me gustaría eliminar el botón y hacer que la función se "encienda" nada más entrar en la página.

**También me gustaría poder conservar los centros fijos e invariables**

```js
function myMove() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("size0a");   
  var elem2 = document.getElementById("size0b");
  var elem3 = document.getElementById("size0c");
  var pos = 100 ;
  var pos2 = 200 ;
  var pos3 = 300 ;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 80);
  var id2 = setInterval(frame2, 80);
  var id3 = setInterval(frame3, 80);
  function frame() {
    if (pos == 200) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      pos++; 
      elem.style.width = pos + 'px'; 
      elem.style.height = pos + 'px'; 
    }
  }
  function frame2() {
    if (pos2 == 300) {
      clearInterval(id2);
    } else {
      pos2++; 
      elem2.style.width = pos2 + 'px'; 
      elem2.style.height = pos2 + 'px'; 
    }
  }
    function frame3() {
    if (pos3 == 300) {
      clearInterval(id3);
    } else {
      pos3--; 
      elem3.style.width = pos3 - 'px'; 
      elem3.style.height = pos3 - 'px'; 
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: yellow;
}
#size0a {
  position: absolute;
  width:100px;
height:100px;
margin-left:-50px;
margin-top:-50px;
}
#size0b {
  position: absolute;
  width:200px;
height:200px;
margin-left:-100px;
margin-top:-100px;
}
#size0c {
  position: absolute;
  width:300px;
height:300px;
margin-left:-150px;
margin-top:-150px;
}
body{margin:none; overflow:hidden; background: white; background:rgba(255,204,233,1.00) }

.v10{left:20%;}
.v25{left:50%;}
.v40{left:80%;}
.h25{top:50%;}

.point{
 -moz-border-radius: 50%;
 -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
 border-radius: 50%;
 background: black; 
 width:6px;
 height:6px;
 margin-left:-3px;
 margin-top:-3px;
 position:absolute;
 z-index:10000;
}

#malla{
 display:none;
 }
.circle {
 -moz-border-radius: 50%;
 -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
 border-radius: 50%; 
 position:absolute;
 z-index:50;
}
.bg0a{
background:blue;
}
.bg0b{
background:red;
}
.bg0c{
 background:rgba(0,255,8,1.00);
}

.size0a{
width:300px;
height:300px;
margin-left:-150px;
margin-top:-150px;
}
.size0b{
width:400px;
height:400px;
margin-left:-200px;
margin-top:-200px;
}
@media (max-width: 650px) {
#size0a{
width:50px;
height:50px;
margin-left:-25px;
margin-top:-25px;
}
#size0b{
width:100px;
height:100px;
margin-left:-50px;
margin-top:-50px;
}
#size0c{
width:150px;
height:150px;
margin-left:-75px;
margin-top:-75px;
}
```

```html
<button style="position:absolute; z-index:1000;" onclick="myMove()">Click Me</button>

<div id="sec1">
<div id ="size0a" class="circle v25 h25 bg0a"></div>
<div id="centro_azul" class="point v25 h25" style="background:cyan;"></div>
<div id ="size0b" class="circle v10 h25 bg0b"></div>
<div id="centro_rojo" class="point v10 h25" style="background:pink;"></div>
<div id ="size0c" class="circle v40 h25 bg0c"></div>
<div id="centro_rojo" class="point v40 h25" style="background:green;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: quita el nombre de la `functionmyMove(){...}` debería quedar así `function(){...}` y con eso debería ser una función automática que se ejecuta desde el inicio que carga la pagina ó bien pon un `settimeout()` que te llame a la función.

Comment: y en cuanto a las animaciones si deseas que sean infinitas usa los `@keyframes ` de css serian una ayuda muy buena

Comment: Hola Ivan, tiene que ser en javascript o estaria bien una solucion CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno de esta forma Puedes ejecutar tu Script sin el botón que comentabas, espero te sirva.

El cambio que le realice fue el siguiente: cambie la función que se llamaba; **myMove()** por una **función anónima** que se ejecutara automáticamente, es decir quedo al final así; `(function(){ //aquí todo tu script; })();` y todo tu demás código hasta esta respuesta quedo igual.

```js
(function() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("size0a");   
  var elem2 = document.getElementById("size0b");
  var elem3 = document.getElementById("size0c");
  var a = document.querySelectorAll("#size0a, #size0b, #size0c");
  
  var pos = 100 ;
  var pos2 = 200 ;
  var pos3 = 300 ;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 80);
  var id2 = setInterval(frame2, 80);
  var id3 = setInterval(frame3, 80);
  
  function frame() {
    if (pos == 200) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      pos++; 
      elem.style.width = pos + 'px'; 
      elem.style.height = pos + 'px'; 
    }
  }
  function frame2() {
    if (pos2 == 300) {
      clearInterval(id2);
    } else {
      pos2++; 
      elem2.style.width = pos2 + 'px'; 
      elem2.style.height = pos2 + 'px'; 
    }
  }
    function frame3() {
    if (pos3 == 300) {
      clearInterval(id3);
    } else {
      pos3--; 
      elem3.style.width = pos3 - 'px'; 
      elem3.style.height = pos3 - 'px'; 
    }
  }
})();
```

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: yellow;
}
#size0a {
  position: absolute;
  width:100px;
height:100px;
margin-left:-50px;
margin-top:-50px;
}
#size0b {
  position: absolute;
  width:200px;
height:200px;
margin-left:-100px;
margin-top:-100px;
}
#size0c {
  position: absolute;
  width:300px;
height:300px;
margin-left:-150px;
margin-top:-150px;
}
body{margin:none; overflow:hidden; background: white; background:rgba(255,204,233,1.00) }

.v10{left:20%;}
.v25{left:50%;}
.v40{left:80%;}
.h25{top:50%;}

.point{
 -moz-border-radius: 50%;
 -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
 border-radius: 50%;
 background: black; 
 width:6px;
 height:6px;
 margin-left:-3px;
 margin-top:-3px;
 position:absolute;
 z-index:10000;
}

#malla{
 display:none;
 }
.circle {
 -moz-border-radius: 50%;
 -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
 border-radius: 50%; 
 position:absolute;
 z-index:50;
}
.bg0a{
background:blue;
}
.bg0b{
background:red;
}
.bg0c{
 background:rgba(0,255,8,1.00);
}

.size0a{
width:300px;
height:300px;
margin-left:-150px;
margin-top:-150px;
}
.size0b{
width:400px;
height:400px;
margin-left:-200px;
margin-top:-200px;
}
@media (max-width: 650px) {
#size0a{
width:50px;
height:50px;
margin-left:-25px;
margin-top:-25px;
}
#size0b{
width:100px;
height:100px;
margin-left:-50px;
margin-top:-50px;
}
#size0c{
width:150px;
height:150px;
margin-left:-75px;
margin-top:-75px;
}
```

```html
<div id="sec1">
<div id ="size0a" class="circle v25 h25 bg0a"></div>
<div id="centro_azul" class="point v25 h25" style="background:cyan;"></div>
<div id ="size0b" class="circle v10 h25 bg0b"></div>
<div id="centro_rojo" class="point v10 h25" style="background:pink;"></div>
<div id ="size0c" class="circle v40 h25 bg0c"></div>
<div id="centro_rojo" class="point v40 h25" style="background:green;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oye, una cosa más, como hago para que después se reduzcan los tamaños cuando llegan a sus limites en lugar de frenar

Comment: Ok puedes crear otro setInterval con una function similar pero que haga `pos--;` pero mira deja llegó hacerme tiempo para hacer una función generica que te ayude...

Answer (score 2):

Tienes la etiqueta de CSS en la pregunta, así que voy a sugerirte una alternativa basada en animaciones CSS en lugar de JavaScript. Lo que quieres conseguir es una animación sencilla y (en mi opinión) sería más fácil y limpio hacerlo con CSS que con JavaScript.

Algunos de los cambios que he hecho:

- Definir animaciones CSS usando `@keyframes` para las diferentes *media queries*
- En los diferentes elementos, he añadido las reglas CSS para que la animación haga lo que quieres:

  - `animation-name`: es el nombre de la animación (el definido en `@keyframes`)
  - `animation-duration`: es la duración de la animación. En tu código JS estabas haciendo crecer los círculos 1 píxel cada 80 milisegundos hasta 100px, así que he elegido 8 segundos (80 x 100 = 8000 milisegundos = 8 segundos)
  - `animation-direction`: esto dice en qué dirección debe ir la animación, al poner `alternate`, la animación se ejecutará hacia delante y luego hacia atrás.
  - `animation-timing-function`: indica cómo se ejecutará la animación, como la estabas haciendo de manera linear (el mismo cambia en cada paso), ese es el valor que elegí.
  - `animation-iteration-count`: indica cuántas veces se ejecutará la animación. Al usar `infinite` se ejecutará siempre.
- Aunque esto no era necesario: he eliminado los márgenes negativos y en su lugar he puesto un `transform:translate(-50%, -50%)` con el que se obtiene un resultado similar, pero sin necesidad de tener que redefinir los márgenes negativos cada vez para que el círculo quede centrado.

Como puedes ver en este ejemplo, al tener `@keyframes` definidos tanto fuera de la *media query* como dentro de ella, las animaciones se adaptan a los diferentes tamaños (ejecuta el ejemplo, pulsa en el botón "Pantalla completa" y cambia el tamaño de la ventana):

```css
#size0a {
  position: absolute;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  animation-name: frame2;
  animation-duration: 8s;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
#size0b {
  position: absolute;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  animation-name: frame;
  animation-duration: 8s;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
#size0c {
  position: absolute;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  animation-name: frame3;
  animation-duration: 8s;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

body{margin:none; overflow:hidden; background: white; background:rgba(255,204,233,1); }

.v10{left:20%;}
.v25{left:50%;}
.v40{left:80%;}
.h25{top:50%;}

.point{
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: black; 
  width:6px;
  height:6px;
  margin-left:-3px;
  margin-top:-3px;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:10000;
}


.circle {
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%; 
  position:absolute;
  z-index:50;
}
.bg0a{
  background:blue;
}
.bg0b{
  background:red;
}
.bg0c{
  background:rgba(0,255,8,1.00);
}


@keyframes frame {
  from { width:200px; height:200px; }
  to { width:300px; height:300px; }
}
@keyframes frame2 {
  from { width:100px; height:100px; }
  to { width:200px; height:200px; }
}
@keyframes frame3 {
  from { width:300px; height:300px; }
  to { width:400px; height:400px; }
}

@media (max-width: 650px) {
  
  #size0a{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
  }
  #size0b{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
  }
  #size0c{
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
  }
  @keyframes frame {
    from { width:100px; height:100px; }
    to { width:200px; height:200px; }
  }
  @keyframes frame2 {
    from { width:50px; height:50px; }
    to { width:100px; height:100px; }
  }
  @keyframes frame3 {
    from { width:150px; height:150px; }
    to { width:250px; height:250px; }
  }

}
```

```html
<!--<button style="position:absolute; z-index:1000;" onclick="myMove()">Click Me</button>-->

<div id="sec1">
  <div id ="size0a" class="circle v25 h25 bg0a"></div>
  <div id="centro_azul" class="point v25 h25" style="background:cyan;"></div>
  <div id ="size0b" class="circle v10 h25 bg0b"></div>
  <div id="centro_rojo" class="point v10 h25" style="background:pink;"></div>
  <div id ="size0c" class="circle v40 h25 bg0c"></div>
  <div id="centro_rojo" class="point v40 h25" style="background:green;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Alvaro, una dudilla más relativa a esto... cuando hago un fadeIn con clase size0c éste no comparte las propiedades atribuídas por el keyframe a su clase; hay alguna forma de hacer que lo haga? Gracias

Comment: Dime si he comprendido correctamente: quieres que el círculo size0c (el verde), no sólo crezca/decrezca sino que también haga un fadeIn. ¿Entendí bien? ¿Debería hacer fadeOut cuando decrece?

Comment: Nono, perdona, si en el segundo 20 hay un fadeIn de un elemento con la misma clase que el círculo verde lo que ocurre es que entra con las propiedades de la clase por defecto, y no las que comparte con el círculo verde.¿esta forma que me has recomendado de escritura es compatible con todos los navegadores?

Comment: Ok. Si lo que quieres es que otro elemento con clase size0c comparta las propiedades atribuídas por el keyframe, añade las reglas de la animación CSS a esa clase en particular en lugar de al ID y la animación comenzará tan pronto como el elemento sea visible. Sobre compatibilidad: ahora mismo está bien extendida (lo puedes ver en [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=keyframe)), aunque podrías tener problemas con navegadores antiguos (aunque en algunos casos funcionaría con el prefijo de navegador; p.e. @-webkit-keyframes)

Comment: Claro alvaro, ese es el problema que observo, que la animación empieza cuando el nuevo elemento es visible desde el principio y no en el punto en que se encuentra en el elemento ya visible...

Comment: Ya veo. Eso va a complicar la pregunta original un pelín :P

Comment: Igual con un timestamp de javascript para fijar un time-delay variable?

Comment: Sí, sería cuestión de averiguarlo la posición en la que se encuentra la animación y aplicarle un delay negativo al nuevo elemento